# How to install Oracle's sqlplus on a Mac?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I need steps how to install Oracle's sqlplus on a Mac.

Comment: This is a valid question, I just run into this problem and found this question. I wish it had more answers. I don't see why this was voted `off-topic` or `too localised`

Answer (score 5):

- Download `Basic Package` and `SQL*Plus Package` zip files from [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html)
- Add a local repository to `brew` from where the Oracle packages will be installed: `brew tap InstantClientTap/instantclient`
- Copy both Oracle's zip files to `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/instantclienttap/homebrew-instantclient`
- Install the basic package: `brew install instantclient-basic`
- Install the SQL*Plus package: `brew install instantclient-sqlplus`
- Test `sqlplus` by connecting to an existing database: `sqlplus user/password@server:port/sid`

My intention was to improve Joost van Wollingen's article published [here](https://vanwollingen.nl/install-oracle-instant-client-and-sqlplus-using-homebrew-a233ce224bf).

Comment: There is no need to involve brew for this. Just unzip the instant client packages anywhere and update your path to include the binaries and libraries

Comment: Does anyone know where to place tnsname.ora if we go this route with homebrew.